# Shedlock only works on one instance, but not multiple

Tags: spring, concurrency, scheduled-tasks, scheduler, shedlock

I would like to setup Shedlock to guard a sensitive process so that only ONE instance of the process ever runs even when multiple application processes are started.

In my pom.xml

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.javacrumbs.shedlock</groupId>
            <artifactId>shedlock-spring</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.javacrumbs.shedlock</groupId>
            <artifactId>shedlock-provider-jdbc-template</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

My DB:

```sql
CREATE TABLE shedlock(
    name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    lock_until TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    locked_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    locked_by VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (name));
```

My configuration:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class ShedlockConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public LockProvider lockProvider(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplateLockProvider(
                JdbcTemplateLockProvider.Configuration.builder()
                        .withJdbcTemplate(new JdbcTemplate(dataSource))
                        .usingDbTime() 
                        .build()
        );
    }

}
```

My schedule:

```java
@Component
public class SchedulerA {
    @Scheduled(initialDelayString = "${examples.scheduler.initial-delay:PT1S}",
            fixedDelayString = "${examples.scheduler.fixed-delay:PT10S}")
    @SchedulerLock(name = "example_scheduler",
            lockAtLeastFor = "${examples.scheduler.lock-at-least:PT5S}",
            lockAtMostFor = "${examples.scheduler.lock-at-most:PT30S}")
    public void schedule() {
// Implementation not important
    }

}
```

Symptom:
If I start only one instance with multiple SchedulerA classes like SchedulerB, SchedulerC, etc which are all copies of the same code I can see the Shedlock does its thing and only allow one LOCAL instance to execute at a time. But, when I start up multiple Spring Boot applications, they all their schedules concurrently even when they use the same DB, same table, same scheduler name. I also notice no entries in the DB table, but the debug logs also reveals no errors.

Question:
Is this the expected behaviour of Shedlock? Should I research another solution or did I misconfigured something?

Comment: Is lockAtLeastFor 5s too short? From documents : "Lastly, you can set lockAtLeastFor attribute which specifies minimum amount of time for which the lock should be kept. Its main purpose is to prevent execution from multiple nodes in case of really short tasks and clock difference between the nodes."

Comment: @meobeo173, I have replaced the seconds with minutes in the duration of all values and they are still concurrently executing.

Comment: also check date/timezone in all of your instances, and the lock time in shedlock table

Comment: @meobeo173 For my test I am running the instances on the same machine so the clock will be the same (for production it will be different machines). There are no entries in the shedlock table, but the table do exist.

Comment: did you forget to add @EnableSchedulerLock ??

Comment: @meobeo173 Do I have to add it? I though it was only for default values, because each method will have its own values like in the example I posted.

Comment: it's mandatory, check the documents

Comment: @meobeo173 It worked! Now I see "Not executing 'example_scheduler'. It's locked." in the logs and it behave as expected. Post it as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add @EnableSchedulerLock to your configuration class as per documents : "In order to enable schedule locking use @EnableSchedulerLock annotation"

Answer (score 0):

You need to add @EnableSchedulerLock annotation with manadatory parameter defaultLockAtMostFor on your main class from where spring boot application is starting. It will prevent multiple instances of same spring boot application to run scheduled task at a same time.